# Subview of my customView in UIBarButtonItem disappear when using the same subview in other UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

This is how I customise my `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
if DBAppSettings.imageViewForCartBarButtonItem == nil {
    DBAppSettings.imageViewForCartBarButtonItem = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 30, 30))
    DBAppSettings.imageViewForCartBarButtonItem.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}

let wrapperView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
wrapperView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

wrapperView.addSubview(DBAppSettings.imageViewForCartBarButtonItem)
let cartBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: wrapperView)
```

Once I setup my `UIBarButtonItem` it looks ok:

[image]

but when I push and then pop view controller (this means that I use the same green subview to load it into another `UIBarButtonItem`) from the navigation stack, it is yellow. It looks like green subview is deallocated. Why?

[image]

This is how I keep references to my green subview:

```
class DBAppSettings: NSObject {
    static var imageViewForCartBarButtonItem: UIImageView!
}
```

**note**:

Everything works fine, when I keep green subview locally:

```
let green = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 30, 30))
green.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

wrapperView.addSubview(green)
```

Comment: were you using `imageViewForCartBarButtonItem` in other view controller?

Comment: Yes, I am using it in almost every controller. I did it because I need to change green imageView's image from every place of the app.

Comment: `UIView` can have one superview. When you add it 2nd time, it's removed from the first button. Docs quote (`addSubview`): _Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview._ So, it's not deallocated, just removed and used elsewhere.

Comment: hence, Do you know the way how can I solve this? I would like to keep reference to every `UIBarButtonItem` through one object (whatever kind). and then change the image in one place to keep changes in every `UIBarButtonItem`. Is it possible?

Comment: Subsequent and too broad question. How many of them? How often do you want to change them? What triggers this change? Many ways to achieve it - IOW how complicated the solution will be. `push-pop` discards the `UIBarButtonItem` from popped controller. Maybe updating it in `viewWillAppear` will be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment. `UIView` can have just one superview. If you add it as a subview 2nd time, it's removed from the first superview and then added to the new one. Check `addSubview...` docs:

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and
>   that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous
>   superview before making the receiver its new superview.

It's not deallocated. It's just removed from your first `wrapperView`.

You can use custom factory method, like the following one:

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {

  static func myBarButtonItem() -> UIBarButtonItem {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(5,5,30,30))
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    let wrapperView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
    wrapperView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    wrapperView.addSubview(imageView)

    return UIBarButtonItem(customView: wrapperView)
  }

}
```

Don't be afraid even if you use `UIImage`s. `UIImage`s are cached, shared, ... One image is not multiple times in memory, just once. Talking about `UIImage` & `init?(named name: String)`.

In every `UIViewController`, just use `UIBarButtonItem.myBarButtonItem()`. Multiple instances of your `wrapperView`, `imageView` and one `UIImage`.

Comment: In my case it is not about memory, but about quick change one image to update same image in every `UIBarButtonItem`.